# Delphi Get LocationSensor Speed on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm currently developing a Localization Android App on Delphi / RADStudio Tokyo 10.2

I'm pretty new to delphi programming, and I am looking for a way to get the speed property of the `LocationSensor`. Through the documentation I found this:

```
LocationSensor1.Sensor.Speed
```

But it always returns `NaN`, so I did some digging and found this in `System.Sensors`:

```
function TCustomLocationSensor.GetDoubleProperty(Prop: TProperty): Double;
begin
  Result := NaN;
end;
```

So I am confused, am I using the wrong property, or using it wrongly ? If so what should I use, or how should I use it?

**EDIT**

My question differs from [Xe5 locationsensor distance doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939472/xe5-locationsensor-distance-doesnt-work) as I have no problem with GPS precision (or at least it doesn't seem so), allthough they might not be unrelated.The application communicates with a Server, that will display it's position and it's trajectory on a web browser.

For optimal usage, I have to transmit the travelling speed of the device. I thought of using Accelerometer at first, but it didn't fit the situation. Then I stumbled upon this on the embarcadero documentation : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Sensors.TCustomLocationSensor.Speed

This was precisely what I needed, but when i try to get the value it always returns NaN, as explained above. Whilst debugging, I finally found the code showed above in `System.Sensors` and I thought it was strange that the function always returns NaN no matter what happens, as I found no help online ( just a few websites in japanese or russian http://www.360doc.com/content/17/0502/18/9200790_650383719.shtml
http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread1386722.html) I posted here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xe5 locationsensor distance doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939472/xe5-locationsensor-distance-doesnt-work)

Comment: You're much better off learning how to implement Android api LocationServices. The locationsensor is very battery hungry and particularly uncontrollable.

Comment: I might just do that, thanks @nolaspeaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do not use standard firemonkey TLocationSensor. Instead of that try implement solution based on native java classes (JLocationListener).

```
  TAndroidLocationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JLocationListener)
  public
    constructor Create();
    procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderDisabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
  end;
```

in `onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;` you will get instance of current location object (java interface)

For test purposes create notification event with message `location.getSpeed.ToString()`

Here you got similar question
[How to track the user location at full time with a delphi app under android/ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472256/how-to-track-the-user-location-at-full-time-with-a-delphi-app-under-android-ios/43503174#43503174)